# How do you give a specific member a role? Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I had to make an account to post this, but I’m making an `!addrole` command to my bot and I’m having some troubles figuring out how to add the role to the member, it keeps giving me this error

`TypeError: Cannot read property ‘roles’ of undefined`

Here’s what I’ve been working on:

```js
if (!message.content.startswith(prefix) || message.author.client) return;
const arguments = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(‘‘);
const command = arguments.shift().toLowerCase();

if (command === ‘addrole’) {
    const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === ‘ROLE’)
    const userId = arguments[0].slice(2, 19) // users id from the message
    const user = message.guild.members.cache.get(userId) // user itself 
    user.roles.add(role)
}
```

But it keeps giving me the error above, please help.
Also, excuse my capitalization and indexing, I just copied the code from my computer to my phone, my browser was a bit glitchy.
You can also dm on Ralphiboy22#7118

Comment: Are you sending the message in a valid guild?

Comment: Yes, I‘m pretty sure

Comment: Try `console.log(userId)`, does it return what you expect?

Comment: It logs exactly what I except, my id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a really better way to do it, instead of doing userId and user and etc., you can use `message.mentions.members.first()` Like so:

```
const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === ‘Insert role here’)
const target = message.mentions.members.first();
target.roles.cache.add(role)
```

You can also add this on the bottom of the target line:

```
if(!target) message.channel.send(‘User not found!’)
```

Answer (score 1):

`discord.js` v12 and higher uses `Managers`, which means you have to pass it through the `cache` property.

```js
user.roles.cache.add(role)
```

[`GuildMemberRoleManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager)